# How do I disable Android Studio 3.6 multiple fragmentation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

After my update to 3.6 from 3.5, whenever I try starting a new project, two fragments are created automatically and that is very difficult to manage. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you. It is happening because you are not selecting 'Empty Activity' from project template dialog while creating new project. You just have to select 'Empty Activity' while creating new project (like the image below). That's it.

[image]